# Convert NstaggedpointerString to int

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, nstaggedpointerstring

actually i have used this code for converting  NstaggedpointerString to string

```
NSString  *index = [responseSelectedAvailibility[i] valueForKey:@"day"];

        NSLog(@"String %@",index);

        int indexDayValue = (int)index;
        NSLog(@" index %d",indexDayValue);

        indexDayValue = indexDayValue-1;

    NSLog(@" index after decrementing %d",indexDayValue);
```

i get output of string is like this

```
String

     (
        1
    )
```

now how i get this 1.

Comment: The problem isn't converting that string to an int, the problem is that you haven't turned on essential warnings in your compiler, so it lets you get away with this nonsense.

Comment: The main issue is obviously the value-for-key-trap.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. Two different thing. This question is about a bug in the JSONDictionary parsing. A number is being parsed into an NSTaggedPointerString. Also, gnasher729 is wrong. Its a bug in how the parsing works. Long numbers are being converted properly but short numbers are not. Any other JSON parser would and does see these as numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this:

```
int indexDayValue = (int)index;
```

with this:

```
int indexDayValue = [index intValue];
```

**Edit:**

> [__NSArrayI intValue] unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f940053f7e0

That's because `index` is in fact an array, not a string. Do the following:

```
NSDictionary *dict = responseSelectedAvailibility[i];
NSArray *dayArray = dict[@"day"];
NSString *dayIndexString = [dayArray firstObject];
int dayIndex = [dayIndexString intValue];
```

Comment: P.S. And don't call a string `index`, it is confusing. At least it should be `indexString`

Comment: [__NSArrayI intValue] unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f940053f7e0. getting this error

Comment: @MadBurea Check the update.

Comment: And if "day" is an array, then you better figure out what it means if the array contains 0 or 2 or 3 values. PS. You open yourself up to a DoS attack by having no checks in your code whatsoever.

Comment: bullshit.. i haven't seen this it within an array..  thanks